# dotnet cli throwing error because of missing one dll

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli

I have recently installed .Net core 2.0 in my windows 7 system. But, while running dotnet command on command prompt i am getting error same as in attached snap.

[image]

Please let me know if any of you have faced this issue.

Thanks in Advance,
Vivek

Comment: How did you install net core?

Comment: Do you have Service Pack 1 for Windows 7 installed?